# How to use api based TTS service (Murf, Wellsaid etc) with Amazon Connect?

Tags: text-to-speech, amazon-connect, amazon-polly

I'm building an ai based voice reservation system on Amazon Connect and want to use 3rd party NTTS like murf.ai or WellSaid labs. I am wondering how can I use these services instead of Polly. All the tutorials and articles use Polly :/

Answer (score 0):

Although this may be technically possible, it certainly wouldn't be practical.

You can only use the inbuilt TTS in connect to do TTS directly. Any other prompt has to be a audio file, either loaded in connect or stored in an s3 bucket.

So to use a third party TTS engine you'd need to call a lambda that uses a 3rd party TTS API to create the audio file. Then save that audio file to s3 then use the play prompt block to play the file from s3.

I'm guessing that this process would be too slow to be practical in a contact flow.